# Gitlab push error : unpack failed

Tags: git

When I'm pushing some new branch to remote repo I'm getting following error:

```
error: unpack failed: unable to create temporary object directory
To <repoUrl>
 ! [remote rejected] <branchName> -> <branchName> (unpacker error)
error: failed to push some refs to '<repoUrl>'
```

What might be the issue?

Thanks,

Comment: Did you or someone else make any changes recently locally or on the remote repository?  I've never seen this error, but this is the first thing I might look for.

Comment: can you please try with git repack. It may help. For more details you may check this link:- https://www.andyjarrett.co.uk/2009/10/08/unpacker-error-when-pushing-git/

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen actually I made some changes in the repo.. but it's usual workflow for git I suppose

Comment: @ManishSoni repack helped. Thanks!